# iterating a simple loop in python

Tags: python

Basically, open a file  called names.txt, use it to create a list.

then, in another function, i pass that list in as argument. Below is the function:

```
#prints the list to the screen 
def printList(nameList):
    for n in nameList:
        print(n)
```

for whatever reason, it gives me this error: "builtins.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

I was assuming that maybe its attempting one too many iterations, and getting a blank position? Not sure. I tried doing the loop as:

```
def printList(nameList):
    for n in range(0, namelist+1):
        print(n)
```

or something close to that anyway, but this only printed a numbered list, not the content of the list.

I placed the whole source on pastebin: 
http://pastebin.com/CyyhU882

Content of the text file it opens: 
http://pastebin.com/HNeqw9Nv

****as an added note, when I debug this I get the desired output, but when it reaches the end of the file is when it gives the exception****
help?

Comment: How do you create this list that you pass in?

Comment: The issue is you are calling printList with `None` as its argument somewhere.  Can you paste the calling code?

Comment: I fixed the NONE issue by changing line 14 to just nameList.sort()

Comment: THe list is created by reading a text file, similar to this: this = open('file.txt', 'r')
this.readlines()
this.close()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a common problem: you thought that `list.sort()` returns a reference to the sorted list.  It does not; it returns `None`.

Change line 14 to just

```
nameList.sort()
```

Or if you really want, you can do this:

```
nameList = sorted(nameList)
```

This is because of command/query separation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation

EDIT: Also, this line is clearly wrong:

```
result = nameList[n].rstrip('\n')
```

The `for` loop sets `n` to one of the names.  The above should just be:

```
result = n.rstrip('\n')
```

But then you want to print the index where you found the name.  To get the index, you need to look up `enumerate()` and use it:

```
for i, n in enumerate(nameList):
```

And you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name, because it is a built-in class in Python.  Better to use `lst` or `L`.

Comment: this did manage to fix the problem I was having. However, now I have another issue:

Comment: Fixed the problem. Thanks. Now I have searching issues-- no matter which name I search for it always points to index 0...

Comment: I came up with another way of getting the index, but thank you for showing me that. What I ended up using was an accumulator which I set to = before the first iteration, and added += 1 to each loop. Worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably because `name_list` is `None`

Look at how you are initialising the parameters you are passing to the function

In the second example, you have `nameList` and `namelist`, is it possible you are mixing the two up?

eg.

```
nameList = None
# some other stuff
namelist = ["ann", "bob", "colin"] # this is creating a new variable 
                                   # instead of rebinding nameList
printList(nameList)
```

generally it's a bad idea to have variable names that look so similar

Comment: I double checked. the first example is accurate. The second example I just randomly typed to explain my attempted fix.

Comment: as an added note, when I debug this I get the desired output, but when it reaches the end of the file is when it gives the exception

Comment: @user2962806, so when you get to the end of the file, you're calling the function with a `nameList` of `None`. You should show us that code too.

Comment: right... because its looking for the next position 'n', which is nonexistent. question is how do I correct it? Heres the full program if it helps: http://pastebin.com/CyyhU882

Comment: `nameList.sort()` is inplace. It returns `None`. Just use `nameList.sort()` instead!